# Установка MoviePy в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, install

Собственно, как установить MoviePy в PyCharm? Пытался через добавление модулей, пишет что установил, а на деле не работает.

```
import moviepy
from moviepy import *
import  os
i = 0
directory = 'D:\Документы\проекты\заготовки' # адрес папки 
tema = 'D:\Документы\проекты\обложка' # адрес обложки
oblojka = os.listdir(tema) # берем файл обложки в массив если туда ничего не 
сувать то его номер будет "0"
files = os.listdir(directory) # собираем все файлы в папке в массив
print(files[i])
volume = len(files) #определяем размер массива
print(volume)
while i <= volume:
    clip = VideoFileClip(files[i])
    i+=1
    print(clip)
```

Выдает вот это:

```
clip = VideoFileClip(files[i])
NameError: name 'VideoFileClip' is not defined
```

Comment: что не работает? Какая ошибка вылизает? А так я пользуюсь anacondoй, чтобы загружать библиотеки

Comment: Автор, покажите в вопросе остальной код. У вас выше есть импотирование, например `from moviepy.editor import *`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение проблемы во втором коментарии, надо было прописать

```
from moviepy.editor import *
```

Спасибо товарищу "gil9red"!